# Newsletter: How is it possible to determine how many people opened the e-mail?

Tags: analysis, newsletter

**Exact duplicate of [Is there a way to determine whether an e-mail reaches its destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185204/is-there-a-way-to-determine-whether-an-e-mail-reaches-its-destination)**

Hi all,

I heard that it's possible to determine how many people opened a newsletter and analyze WHEN they opened the mail.

I just wanted to know how that's possible... is it necessary to generate a "read confirmation" or is such an analysis possible without letting the recipient know?

Thanks a lot for your input...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See also [Is there a way to determine whether an e-mail reaches its destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185204/is-there-a-way-to-determine-whether-an-e-mail-reaches-its-destination), my answer repeated below:

> If you make the email HTML based, you
>   can include images in it which contain
>   URLs with information unique to the
>   recipient. You could structure your
>   application so that these URLs trigger
>   some code to mark that particular
>   email as read before returning the
>   required image data.
>
> To be totally effective, the images
>   would have to form a key part of the
>   email, so that the recipient has to
>   make their email client grab the
>   images. You could also make the plain
>   text part of the email just contain a
>   URL to retrieve the full message,
>   again allowing you to track receipt.
>
> *How far you take these ideas depends on why you need to know it's been read
>   and to what extent you want to
>   potentially annoy the recipient with
>   an email they can't cut'n'paste, read
>   easily on mobile device, listen to
>   with a screenreader, etc...*

Comment: Modern email-clients do not download images unless the user approves it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to guarantee that someone has opened your newsletter e-mail. But you can get a clue of how many time it was opened by embedding a one pixel image in you mail and use the statistics of you web server to determine how often it was requested.

Comment: However, nowadays email clients and web mail applications load external resources such as an embedded image only on demand.