# Mailengine with .NET API

Tags: .net, api, email, mailing

I am looking for a mailengine that supports

- Sending emails
- Catching bounced emails
- Support read confirmations
- Show reports of mailing statistics (how many received/bounced)
- Expose everything through an API that can be called using .Net

Does anyone know of any? It doesn't have to be free (always nice though) but it can't be a subscription. It has to be a one time purchase.

I tried googling for them but I couldn't find one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm aware of a couple of partial solutions, but not one big package:

- Sending e-mails can be done via the normale .Net classes
- Catching bounced emails can be done by reading the POP3 mailbox like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx
- Support read confirmations, can be done using a tracker image (see [Newsletter: How is it possible to determine how many people opened the e-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519820/newsletter-how-is-it-possible-to-determine-how-many-people-opened-the-e-mail)). As far as I know is the Outlooks read confirmation system just a header that includes a callback e-mailaddress. You might be able to implement that with 2., not sure.
- Show reports of mailing statistics (how many received/bounced), can easily be generated

You should be able to hack something together quite fast. There is no one big solution to do this, unless you want to buy a full newsletter system or something.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this project I just found on Code Project will help: [Email Component for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/cpSphereEmailComponent.aspx)

It seems to have most if not all of the necessary components.

Comment: This is more like a mailing component that integrates in .NET
What I am looking for is something more like a service that monitors a queue and processes mailings that are fed into it. On top of that it should keep track of statistics and expose all this through an API.
It really surprises me that there isn't something similar out there already. I wonder why.