# I want acknowledgment of mail

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to determine whether an e-mail reaches its destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185204/is-there-a-way-to-determine-whether-an-e-mail-reaches-its-destination)
>   [PHP: Check who had read sent email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603850/php-check-who-had-read-sent-email)

I need a php or zend framework code which return a acknowledgment when I send a mail.
If user receives a mail, or not, or may be email is not correct, or when user open this mail; in all these cases I to get a acknowledgement.

How do I do this?

Comment: Impossible to do reliably. Maybe I can find the duplicate...

Comment: You can request delivery confirmations but they are optional for the recipient. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078251/delivery-reports-and-read-receipts-in-php-mail

Comment: I had already try this (X-Confirm-Reading-To,Disposition-Notification-To) but no effect.

Comment: as said, there is no reliable way to do this due to the nature of E-Mail.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can know if a user opened a mail to listen for resources (images) that will download to the client (if they allow downloads) otherwise you are in the dark.

Checking the mail was sent and if the address is valid can be done but only to a certain extend the server that sends the message will report if the message could be sent but that will only be the status of the sent message on that specific server. You could setup some kind of mechanism that listens for addresses that are reported by other servers as invalid but not all the servers do this ...

You could use a third-party provider to handle the acknoweldgements for you which will lift the burden from you. Like [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) but they too have limited ways to do this.

**Just my 2 cents**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the mail being opened, you will need to embed an image in the e-mail. This image is generated by a PHP url like `<img src="domain.com/index.php/generate_image/123">` where 123 is the User ID you put in the e-mail so you can track which user opened that e-mail.

Comment: These kinds of images are blocked by most E-Mail clients by default though.

Comment: Note that most e-mail clients these days don't load images automatically. *edit:* and Pekka beats me to it.